# Minikube and ingress in local env

Tags: kubernetes

i am working in local environment with minikube
i have 2 services called
frontend-service

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: transport
```

backend service

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

i configured and ingress like this

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: local
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test-api.local.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: test.local.it
    http:
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

that's because i want to, based on host name, route the traffic on the right services.

i start minikube with minikube start
and start the tunnel with minikube tunnel
the hosts are correctly mapped on local file hosts

`127.0.0.1       test.local.it test-api.local.it`

the issue is that for both hosts the response is always from the backend-service.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check whether the hosts in local host files are pointing toward the Minikube IP correctly. Also, there might be a formatting issue in the configured ingress, check if the indentations are in the correct manner for “-**path**” in “**http**” block for both services .

Comment: thanks for the hints, but i already mapped the minikube ip in my hosts file with the correct hostname but nothing changed

i tried k8s for docker desktop because im working on mac, but same result

Comment: Have you tried correcting the indentations of the **‘- path’** in the ingress service’s **http** block? They should be vertically aligned with each other,reduce the indentation for the **‘- path’** in the front-end service to align it with the back-end service’s **‘- path’**.indentation errors can lead to unexpected results or failures when parsing or processing YAML files.

Comment: Another thing you can check: Port forward to the `frontend-service` service and do a request to `http://localhost` -- do you get the `frontend` or `backend` response. If you get the `backend` response, your service selectors for the `frontend-service` are incorrect.